# How to clean the MAF sensor on a 1997 Nissan Altima?

Tags: engine, nissan, air-intake, maf

I have a 1997 Nissan Altima sedan. I’ve been told the issues I’m having with my car is from the mass air flow sensor. I was wondering how to clean/repair this sensor and contact points the best? What would be the best way to do this besides replace the sensor?

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had a clue or had watched this video before I spent over $600 way back in 2003 when my MAF went bad in my 2000 Sentra. The video should speak for itself:

http://youtu.be/vPT8rL0noYg